# Large address aware TFS build server

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

My application needs to have `LARGEADDRESSAWARE`. I can execute this post build script when building locally:

```
call "$(DevEnvDir)..\tools\vsvars32.bat
editbin /largeaddressaware $(TargetPath)"
```

When I commit this change, a `CI` build will be triggered, but it ends with this error:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets (4291): The command "call "*Undefined*..\tools\vsvars32.bat
editbin /largeaddressaware e:\B\5\27\bin\MyApplication.exe"" exited with code 9009.
```

Any suggestions on how to configure this properly?

Comment: Don't use post build-script from VS.  As you see some of the variable don't resolve.  If you really want to keep this I would change $(DevEnvDir)..\ to be the full path to the vsvars32.bat.  But that entails that you have VS installed on the build server.

Answer (score 1):

I think devenvvar variable is not defined, not sure if visual studio sets it up, or you need ro run some script before. Personally i would add editbin to repository and use relative path to it. Much more reliable